# Unable to run multiple monitors in Windows 10 Pro via Boot Camp

Tags: display, bootcamp, windows, bluetooth

Problem: I cannot run more than one external monitor (Dell 2415, 24") when running Windows 10 Pro in Boot Camp on my MacBook Pro. Also unable to run a bluetooth mouse in that configuration. Verified that I can run 4 external monitors in the MacOS, and also a Bluetooth mouse. I need to run 4 external monitors. Anyone have a similar problem or possible solution? And, please, don't suggest buying a Windows computer. Don't want to do that.

Comment: We run multiple displays in VMWare fusion. Perhaps that might let you know your windows configuration is up to that many displays on the Mac hardware? Also - how are you getting the 4 to work in macOS? (or is this the latest Touch Bar MBP with 4 thunderbolt ports)

Comment: Question before solution, how old is your macbook?